# Is it possible to use X-Pack to limit Kibana login attempts?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fail2ban, xpack

Does X-Pack have a capability similar to fail2ban, to prevent against brute force attacks?  If not, can fail2ban (Or equivalent) be configured to secure Kibana UI logins?

Answer (score 1):

If you connect elastic to an external realm using x-pack, you will be able to limit the login attempts if the external realm has such a feature (LDAP for example).

But there is no way at this moment for limiting login attempts with file or native realms.

There is already a feature request covering that need: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/18491